# Django - how to add data using conditional statement in a separate python script

Tags: python, django

**Purpose/Intension**

I have created Django Model with the result being an sqlite3 database. I now want to use a separate python script to add to that database based on some conditional logic.

**Problem**

I am new to Django and Python so I am not sure how to interrogate the database and then add some values based on the return result from that interrogation using a separate python script.

This is my Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Author(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the Author of the stocknote.
    '''
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Stock(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the stock info.
    '''
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    ticker_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    latest_stock_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4, null=True, blank=True)
    datetime_of_last_quote = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker_code

class Note(models.Model):
    '''
    Model representing the Authors note.
    '''
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    note = models.TextField()
    ticker_code = models.ForeignKey(Stock)
    date_note_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    alert_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=4, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.note
```

Now imagine I have added data into the database so it contains data in all the fields except for the field 'latest_stock_price' which is empty.

What i want to do in a separate python script - lets call it *interrogate-db.py* - is have programatic logic like so:

```
If 'GOOG' is in 'ticker_code' then
   add '1.234' to the latest_stock_price for GOOJ
```

The best i could achieve in writing interrogate-db.py is:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject_project.settings')
import django
django.setup()
from myproject.models import Author, Stock, Note

def add_latest_price():
    for t in Stock.objects.values_list('ticker_code'):
        if 'GOOJ' in t:
            ...What goes here?...
```

What should be the syntax to add 1.234 to latest_stock_price if GOOJ is in t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for stock in Stock.objects.all():
    if stock.ticker_code == 'GOOJ':
        stock.latest_stock_price = 1.234
        stock.save()
```

Or

```
Stock.objects.filter(ticker_code='GOOJ').update(latest_stock_price=1.234)
```

Comment: It should be `=` in place of `in` and `=` instead of `+=`.

Comment: thanks @AshishNitinPatil I took that condition like it was python code. :P

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help Ravi and Ashish, that solved my problem.